# Fixing a booleaned violin?

Tags: modifiers

I have no other way to title the question I have. I have a hollow violin model that I'm trying to cut through with boolean shapes (example pic included of what I'm trying to make.)[image: Violin Bow]

What I'm trying to do is figure out how to create a way to close the hollow gap left behind. Not fully fill the inside but just to basically make a wall from the front to the back where I cut.[image: Hollow Violin][!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use filler in edit mode, if I understand your question.
Go into Edit mode, in vertice selection mode, and hit Ctrl-Numpad 1 to make go into Y view. Turn on X-ray mode so it looks something like this (this is just a sphere, not a violin)

[image]

Group select two vertices (it selects both the two in the front and the two in the back), and hit "f" on your keyboard, like this:

[image]

There should now be a face in between these four vertices, like this:

[image]

Just do this to every set of vertices in your circle, until it looks like this:

[image]

If you want to, you can also shade it smooth in object mode, but there's enough pictures on this post already ;-)

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try this as soon as I can but I'm fairly sure this will do exactly what I want!

Comment: I hope this helps you! Happy Blending! 